# Between onCreate() and onPostCreate()

Tags: android

Are there any Runnables from the UI thread MessageQueue executed between `onCreate()` an `onPostCreate()`? In other words, is it possible that my AsyncTask's `onPostExecute()` method will be called in between?

Answer (score 16):

onPostCreate() is mainly intented for framework use (although you can override it).
The docs say that it is called after onStart() and onRestoreInstanceState().

This might lead to the assumption that it might be called before onResume() and thus probably before the message loop is dispatching events (including AsyncTask's onPostExecute() method), meaning your onPostExecute() will only fire after onPause().

As onPostCreate() is not properly documented and not really intended for application use - I might want to say it is not a good idea to rely on any observed behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, I need this in my AbstractActivity, because I want to run some code in the subclasses after the Activity is set up but before message loop is dispatching starts.

Comment: Examining Android's 4.4.3 source, onPostCreate() is (only) called by ActivityThread#performLaunchActivity and always before onResume().

Answer (score 1):

onPostCreate() call after onStart.

onCreate() is first state of new activity.

onPostCreate() behave same as onCreate() when activity come from on another activity.

FYI :onPostCreate() not well document.